# How to get the account type name and icon for a contact list group?

Tags: java, android

I'm able to retrieve a list of contact groups from Android's contacts provider using this segment of code:

```
// Create a string array with the fields to retrieve for each group
final String[] groupsProjection = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.Groups._ID,
        ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE,
        ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME,
        ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE
        };

// Create a cursor for iterating over the groups
Cursor groupsCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,
        groupsProjection, null, null, null);
```

Upon retrieval I wish to display a list of groups to the user, and show the account type's icon alongside the result (for example, for the account type **com.google** I wish to display Google's icon, Facebook's icon for Facebook accounts...).

How can I retrieve the icon for each account type, preferably without having to add the ACCOUNT_MANAGER permission?

Answer (score -1):

```
if (groupsCursor .getCount() > 0) {
     while (groupsCursor .moveToNext()) 
            {

             String  id = groupsCursor .getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));

                String icon = groupsCursor 
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.ICON));
                 //get more column values of each contact.

    }
}
```

Comment: Even if there had been a field called ContactsContract.Contacts.ICON (and there isn't), I wish to retrieve the icon of the account, not the contact's photo